# nodeTypedValue for Firefox?

Tags: javascript, xml

IE provides a method to access a XML node value data type, called [`nodeTypedValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms762308%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). Is there something similar for Firefox/Webkit?

Mozillas [`nodeType`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/NodeType) returns the type of the node but not the type of its contents :(

Answer (score 2):

I know it's to late for the answer. Yes, it's possible, just use "textContent": `objXML[i].textContent`

Comment: Thanks! textContent returns the type of the content?